# Trying to update data to compass using mongoose but it shows error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie and learning mongoose. I am trying to connect with local server and update data to mongoDB Compass but its' throwing error. I am not able to understand what mistake I am doing. Kindly help me to solve it.

```
db.on("connection", () => console.log("Connected Successfully"));
db.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Disconnected Successfully"));
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
firstEmployee.save(function (err, res) {
if (err) throw error;
console.log(res);
});
db.close();
});
```

and error is = throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: In the line `if (err) throw error;` where does `error` get its value?

Comment: This line `if (err) throw error;` should be `if (err) throw err;` or `if (err) throw new Error('Custom Error Message');`

Comment: thanks it's solved.